# How to add variant icon in a Lightning Datatable in a LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have the column in the data table which will display the `"utility:success",` Based on the condition my controller will return the `selectedIcon` value and display the icon as below.

[image]

Now I', trying to add `variant` of the Icon It's not applying, Can anyone help me on this.

tried by adding this `iconName: { fieldName: "selectedIcon", variant: "brand" }`  still not working

```
<template>
   <lightning-datatable key-field="id" columns={cols} data={data}>
   </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

```
    @track cols = [
         {
      initialWidth: 30,
      fieldName: "",
      label: "",
      cellAttributes: {
        iconName: { fieldName: "selectedIcon"}
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Program Name",
      fieldName: "programName"
    },
    {
      label: "Start - End Date",
      fieldName: "startEndDate"
    }
    ];



@track data = [
{
"id": "a012w00000BsGhwAAF",
"programName": "Week 1 : 3D printing",
"selectedIcon": "utility:success",
"startEndDate": "08/10/2020 - 08/14/2020"
},
{
"id": "a012w00000BsGhxAAF",
"programName": "Week 2 : AutoCad design",
"startEndDate": "08/10/2020 - 08/14/2020"
}
]
```

Comment: Have you tried to update the SVG icon color in component CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `utility:success`, You can use `action:approval`

[image]

```
@track data = [
{
"id": "a012w00000BsGhwAAF",
"programName": "Week 1 : 3D printing",
"selectedIcon": "action:approval",
"startEndDate": "08/10/2020 - 08/14/2020"
},
{
"id": "a012w00000BsGhxAAF",
"programName": "Week 2 : AutoCad design",
"startEndDate": "08/10/2020 - 08/14/2020"
}
]
```

```
@track cols = [
         {
      initialWidth: 30,
      fieldName: "",
      label: "",
      cellAttributes: {
        iconName: { fieldName: "selectedIcon"}
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Program Name",
      fieldName: "programName"
    },
    {
      label: "Start - End Date",
      fieldName: "startEndDate"
    }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the option variant is not available with `cellAttributes`. Only these options are supported, `iconName, iconLabel, iconPosition, iconAlternativeText`. The `variant` is available if you use a button-icon or a button type.

Refer Appending an Icon to Column Data section in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable).

But the **good news** is, you can create your custom column data types by extending the standard `lightning-datatable` component.

See the **Creating Custom Data Types** section of the data table [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable).